# Move my liquid to make me equal

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, integer

You are given 4 positive integers: volume of the first container (`v1`), volume of the second container (`v2`), volume of the liquid in the first container (`l1`), and volume of the liquid in the second container (`l2`). Your task is to move some of the liquid from container 1 to container 2, making the amount of empty space in the containers equal to each other, outputting how much liquid should be moved.

### An example

Here is an example of some possible input (formatted for the ease of test cases. The input isn't formatted.):

```
8 11
6  5
```

Here, you need to make sure that the differences between the volumes and the containers are equal. Currently the difference is not equal:

```
  8 11
- 6  5
======
   6 2
```

So we need to try to make them equal, by taking some of the values in one container to another container:

```
  8 11
- 4  7
======
  4  4
```

After you have succeeded, output how much liquid you need to take from container 1 to container 2. Therefore the above example should output `2`.

### Test cases

```
15 16
 9  2
```

We move into this state:

```
 15 16
- 5  6
======
 10 10
```

Therefore `4` is the expected result.

### Test case #2

```
16 12
13  1
```

We move into this state:

```
 16 12
- 9  5
======
  7  7
```

Therefore `4` is the expected output.

### Test case #3

```
20 12
10 2
```

Moved:

```
 20 12
-10 2
======
 10 10
```

Therefore `0` is the expected output.

### More test cases

(They don't have explanations as this should be quite clear)

```
12 5
9  0 -> 1

9 11
7  3 -> 3
```

### Rules

- The test cases will be made so that the result is always possible as a positive integer. The result will **never** be a decimal.
- Input can be taken in any convenient and reasonable format.
- Output can be given in any convenient and reasonable format.
- The input string will be made so that a moving is always possible without involving decimals or negative numbers. Also there will not be more liquid than how much a container can hold.
- Of course, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer in each language consisting of the fewest number of bytes wins. Happy golfing!
- An extra restriction for the test cases: you can assume that there is always going to be space available in the second container. So a test case like this:

```
10 2
 2 2
```

is not going to be a valid testcase.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6) / C#, 21 bytes

```javascript
(v,V,q,Q)=>V-Q-v+q>>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZckxCoAgGAbQvZMofYa/UNSgd2hpj9IoQivD6xuN0VvfNqYxTtd63MKH2WanM0sYcKLn2gyiF6k8jaE8BR/Dbqs9LMyxFkRoUHNefINqUIMO6jdKghRIvpUf) (JS)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXooOMFYCEnUKagu1/jTKdMJ1CnUBNW7sw3UDdMu1COzvD/9Zc4UWZJak@mXmpGmkaFjqGhjpmOqaamqjihqY6hmY6ljpG6BJGBjqGRjqGBmCZ/wA) (C#)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Nice catch. :)

Comment: Apart from the `=>` vs `->` it's also [a polyglot with Java 8 and CoffeeScript 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198114/52210) (your `>>1` also saved a byte in my answer). :)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
®β;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0Lpzm6z//4821VEwBGEzHQWzWAA)

Input is an array of volumes in the order [first liquid, first container, second container, second liquid].

Alternative 3-byter:

```
ÆÆ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cNvhNuv//6OjDU11FExjdRSiDc10FMxiYwE)

Input is a nested array: [[first container, first liquid], [second container, second liquid]].

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ISH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98z2OP/w537rB81zFHQtVN41DDX@nA71@H2R01rIv//j@aKjjbSMTSL1Yk2NNWxjI3VAQoY6hgagwTMdAyNICJGIJZOtJGBjqFBbCxXLAA)

A monadic link taking as its argument `[[l1, v1], [v2, l2]]` and returning the volume needed to move.

A relatively rare ASCII-only Jelly answer!

### Explanation

```
I   | Increments
 S  | Sum
  H | Half
```

Comment: Well, it's ASCII-ISH...

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
-±¿-¿+½:0<[±]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////0P5D@3XBSPvQXisDm@hDG2P//7fgMuMyNOQyBQA)

A port of Arnauld's original javascript answer. Takes input in form of:

```
volume1
container1
volume2
container2
```

*-1 byte by utilising implicit input correctly.*

Answer (score 2):

## [<s>Perl 6</s> Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```perl6
(*-*-*+*)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfQ0sXCLW1NPWN/ltz5SYWKFQXJ1YqpCnUqMTX6kSb6ZjqWOgYGlpb6hjpGJrqGJpZGxrrGAJpHUMja0MDoKiRAYgZa/0fAA)

Edit: I realized that I could take the parameters in any order. Four parameters are: liquid in container 1, liquid in container 2, volume of container 1, volume of container 2.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8 / CoffeeScript 2, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```java
(V,v,L,l)->v-l-V+L>>1
```

Port of [*@Grimmy*'s second 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198100/52210).
-1 byte by porting @Arnauld's approach, golfing the `(...)/2` I had to `...>>1`.

[Try it online in Java 8.](https://tio.run/##dZCxasMwFEX3fMVDk4yeTeQS0xLqJaubJeCldFBltyhVlBApglKy9gP6if0RV1JESYcuF3Q4cK/eVnhRboe3SWphLTwIZT5mAMq48fgi5Ajr@EwAJI3ZY0yfskupi2VwzrMQ1gmnJKzBwD1MtEePHeqibH2py551bcunZRQPp2cdxOz7vRpgF7rpxh2VeX18AlFcit1oHb1FzrHBRSrKjC@QN3iH9R/YIK@R3yC/pvU80Xl2r5em5iT997fLjM27deOu2p9cdQgLnTaUrDj1hPWMIGjCOkYKEGaAVR2xz1hH/P35BYSZSv5eJA85Tz8)
[Try it online in CoffeeScript 2.](https://tio.run/##ZckxCoAgGAbQvZMofYa/oNSQJ3D2AqIRSEaG1zcao7e@UFKKsYZrP2/V09qZR4ND5sI2kYUfnbXUQzlqyXHKZWOJzSCCgeZ8@AZpkMEC9RslQQok3@oP)

**Explanation:**

```java
(V,v,L,l)->    // Method with four integer parameters and integer return-type
   v-l         //  Calculate the difference between the volume and liquid of container 1
      -V+L     //  Subtract the difference between the volume and liquid of container 2
          >>1  //  Divide that result by 2 (by bit-shifting once towards the right)
```

Comment: [Coffescript polyglot](https://tio.run/##ZckxCoAgGAbQvZMofYa/YNSQd2jxAqIRSGaG1zcao7c@l0LwvrhrP2/VwtJYhUXGyoWxYhW1z8ZQc@koKfohpo0FNoEIIzTn3TdIg0bMUL9REqRA8q32AA). (Not a JavaScript polyglot because of `->` vs `=>`).

Comment: @Grimmy Added. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 79 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Dupe_0][T    N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input_vol1][S N
S _Dupe_input_vol1][S N
S _Dupe_input_vol1][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input_liq1][T S S T   _Subtract_vol1-liq1][S N
S _Dupe_vol1-liq1][S N
S _Dupe_vol1-liq1][T    N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input_vol2][S N
S _Dupe_input_vol2][S N
S _Dupe_input_vol2][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input_liq2][T S S T   _Subtract_vol2-liq2][T  S S T   _Subtract_(vol1-liq1)-(vol2-liq2)][S S S T  S N
_Push_2][T  S T S _Integer_divide_((vol1-liq1)-(vol2-liq2))/2][T    N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QQDIQnA4FRRQBTBkwSrAqjiBBCdQ7v9/Q0MuUy4LLjMA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer vol1 = STDIN as integer
Integer liq1 = STDIN as integer
Integer vol2 = STDIN as integer
Integer liq2 = STDIN as integer
Integer diff1 = vol1 - liq1
Integer diff2 = vol2 - liq2
Integer diffOfDiff = diff1 - diff2
Integer result = diffOfDiff / 2
Print result as integer to STDOUT
```

Since the integers are guaranteed to be positive, it uses them as heap-address for the next input in line with some duplicates, saving bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 16 bytes

```
=(B1-D1-A1+C1)/2
```

Same approach as others

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>27</s> <s>26</s></sup> 25 bytes

Saved a bytes thanks to [meetaig](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59449/meetaig)!!!

```python
lambda a,b,c,d:b-d-a+c>>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcqxCoMwFEbh3ae4o7a/kBsxWKF5kdQhMQQFjSJZ@vQpOAj1jB9n/6Zpi00O709e7Oq8JQuHEb53ta/tc9Sac9gOSjRHMqYDMxTaAQVdGW7BCi/IGyuwBDfgf5fidHH7h76g/ZhjKkP5SFWVfw)

Comment: lambda a,b,c,d:b-d-a+c>>1  would save 1 character=1byte

Comment: @meetaig Thanks! Forgot right-shift had lower precedence than addition/subtraction. :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>29</s></sup> 28 bytes

Saved a bytes thanks to [meetaig](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59449/meetaig)!!!

```c
#define f(a,b,c,d)b-d-a+c>>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3LCsIwFET3/YpQERKcQG@0QSn2S9ykeUhBg4S6Er89igh9zfLMHMZKezPxmvPG@dBHzwI36GDhRCedNDvbtpTvpo9cvAr2zSP1cQi8DPwIImjUgp3Z1l1iCTaBolnMqQZpnKBm@5GuBQ1SoD1obox4pajq11WLkwn@K8kPzxTZQTXFO38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>39</s> 25 bytes

```c
f(a,b,c,d){a=b-d-a+c>>1;}
```

Wrote a testing framework for possible future testcases.

Takes as input 4 integers:

- `a`: capacity of first container
- `b`: capacity of second container
- `c`: amount of liquid in first container
- `d`: amount of liquid in second container

Explanation:

```c
f(a,b,c,d)
```

Function implicitly returning `int` with four arguments of type `int`.

```c
a=
```

A sort of `return` that exploits GCC's code generation when compiling without optimization.

```c
b-d-a+c>>1
```

The main algorithm. There's several steps involved here:

- `b-d`: Subtract the amount of liquid in the second container from the capacity in the second container to get the free space in the second container.
- `-a+c`: Subtract the capacity of the first container and add back the amount of liquid in the second container to get the total free space in both.
- `>>1` After that, divide the amount of free space in both by 2 to get the amount of liquid to move from container one to container two. This is a binary right shift and binary is base 2, so it is equivalent to division by 2 but removes the need for parentheses as the operator precedence of `>>` is lower than that of `+` and `-`. The operator precedence for `/` is higher than that of `+` and `-` so it would require extra parentheses.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZPdToMwFMfveYqzmSUgnVLYNMrYU@wOuWC0aJMJC1RjJDw7HiqfY8vWUFL@/bXnk2j5HkVVFesh2ZOIMKMIvf2SLUMz2m6pW1Z3IokOX4zDJpdMpA8fW62Xwjznmaw1TSQSPkOR6N@pYIZWaICjFiXPZRTmPPcDfxWAB0UBdE2APhF4IWBDSRR7fhSKozZOB@c12LYa2LrlZgTXygnrGooMpQSeCThQlm4XHP858khy5qvAYEXqp/ZBga6mwP8s6bn45Wmsd/kw4BEa7X4get7QkwZo7QzPdJrR2InTTB@lHH2y3P62Tt7cdO2Zk6YJhlKLbk/Zs9BSX@d2FfhWME6rpBdAegraF0D7FHQugE7gjnzMuEQS04/VkVgeicWXziDIY4ZYrM93C/aK3IIR6CeWRa3a5KjPt2Q@6ZrWgenGyO5kG92baF1zdVEN3BWxXoc0885hHVWM7oybGPFP5llGYL5rO2LBIA7FgbNZHVTfKSbQgc1S@3@X1R8)

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
1,$0=($2-$4-$1+$3)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxDYAwEAPAPlO4cAGCiLchERQMQ50BMv5z982RqZ3xLnTlVamN53o484aEjlbUoI4HLg7IUMA/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 19 bytes

```
\d+;?
$*
+`1,1
,
11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZF29qeS0WLSzvBUMeQS4fL0PD/fwsdQ0NrMx1TLkNTHUtrQzMdIy4gYWhsbWgEVGNkoGNoAGIaAQA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+;?
$*
```

Convert to unary and sum the middle two numbers.

```
+`1,1
,
```

Subtract the outer numbers from that sum.

```
11
```

Divide by 2 and convert to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, <s>26</s> 21 bytes

```
Prompt A,B,C,D:.5abs(A-C-B+D
```

Input is a series of prompts for each value.
A = volume1
B = volume2
C = liquid1
D = liquid2

Output is the amount of liquid that needs to be moved from the fuller container to the emptier one.

**Explantion:**

```
Prompt A,B,C,D     ;Prompt the user to input the values
.5abs(A-C-B+D      ;Compute the amount of liquid needed, convert it
                   ;  to a positive number if need be and leave the
                   ;  result in Ans
                   ;Implicit print of Ans
```

**Examples:**

```
prgmCDGF21

A=?15
B=?16
C=?9
D=?2
                   4
prgmCDGF21

A=?11
B=?10
C=?6
D=?7
                   1
```

**Note:**  TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does *not* equal byte count.

Comment: I'm pretty sure just taking the 4 numbers as 4 different variables would be shorter.

Comment: @randomdude999 looks like that's the case, but only by 7 bytes.  this is code golf after all, i guess

Answer (score 0):

## Brainf*ck, 39 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fxw4IbaJ17bRtYkGUna6NTaydDpClC6SjdcESdnr//1dVVRkAAA)

```
,>,>,<[->+<]<[->>-<<]>,[->-<]>[-->+<]>.
```

The input/output are the ASCII values of characters. Using "aaz0" gives "%" as output, as it corresponds to the case

```
97 122

97  48
```

which is solved by moving 37 units of liquid, the % symbol.

Could shave a couple of bytes if the input order could be rearranged, but not sure if that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 13 bytes

Port of [Nick Kennedy's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198110/11261). Takes input in format `[[v1, l1], [l2, v2]]`.

```ruby
+:-**:+|~:/&2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY3LaoNAFIbp1qc40BLUjE5GUtsKaXdC-wpBgpejsagjzlgMvbxIN26y7AOlT1N1giWLc_v455vv4-uujQ7979XNNZgm8BqbUPIGGiz5GyaQV3C3DpFFMeh7KWvhUZrlct9GdsxLGh94jPTFGhw0F6JFQV1DK3nSFgh-W8UaQILpqNYrYzgA8hQqOxe78El_riRm2CgOYD3qnfF-PmBIybxEAQmfEUAHG4jDohiSM8UqmffuvH1OEwuB_3IzbDJx8YFCdhnW-kJgkRrG5fNJPPaxNH9zbGVq3f8sPcs0veXHl0cXjmInrwZ_u2UucQKyfSDsNgg0hdaEDYg5hLkzc6YYWxFnFQTK0Pdq_gE)

### Explanation

```
+:- ** :+ | ~:/ & 2

    **               # Map arguments with...
+:-                  #   Splat pair of elements onto :- (subtract)

       :+ |          # Add, then
            ~:/ & 2  # Divide by 2
```